# What does the VS setting: "enable isolated azure active directory configuration" do?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-active-directory, visual-studio-2017

Tools / options in VS2015 has a setting under Environment / Synchroinized settings that says

```
"enable isolated azure active directory configuration"
```

I wonder if this means that I can have an offline copy of WAAD, or an on premise version.

Answer (score 1):

You only need this setting if you live in China. It setts keys in the registry that lets you only connect to Chinese Azure api endpoints.

At least in Visual Studio 2017 you are unable to login to your Visual Studio Profile and disables you to get a prerelease license.

(See Feedback/Bug https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/7675/cant-sign-into-accounts.html?childToView=17494#comment-17494)